# Is there a way to remove a whole line in a text file if the word is found in python

Tags: python, text

Basically I need this to find the users input and that line which contains that word to delete the whole line. I have no idea what to do and am stuck. May I have some help

```
def delStock(f):
    count = 0
    itemRemove = input("""
Please enter the item you wish to delete.
: """)
    with open("CurrentStock.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open('CurrentStock.txt', "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip(itemRemove) != itemRemove:
                f.write(line)
```

Yes I know this code is really broken right now thats why I need help!

Comment: Read about what [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) does, then use [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead (or maybe better `if needle not in haystack:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a condition to check if `itemRemove` is in `line` or not

```
with open('CurrentStock.txt', "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if itemRemove not in line:
            f.write(line)
```